# Trying to delete emails using open pop library c#

Tags: c#, openpop

I am trying to read emails from an email box and delete some of them upon a certain condition. For that reason I am using open pop library. When I tried to iterate and delete the emails I am getting the following error: 'Cannot access a disposed OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client. Object name: 'OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client'.'

```
Pop3Client popClient = new Pop3Client();

popClient.Connect("mail.test.com", 110, false);
popClient.Authenticate("test.com", "testpass");

int messageCount = popClient.GetMessageCount();

List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);

for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
{
    allMessages.Add(popClient.GetMessage(i));
}

for(int i = allMessages.Count() - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plainText = allMessages[i].FindFirstPlainTextVersion();

    if (plainText != null)
    {
        builder.Append(plainText.GetBodyAsText());
        string emailText = builder.ToString();
        string email = GetStringValue("Email Address: ", emailText).Trim();
    }

    if (email != "test@gmail.com)
    {
        popClient.DeleteMessage(i);
        popClient.Disconnect();           
    }

}
```

Comment: as per http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleDeleteMessage.php have you disconnected to save the changes?  it doesnt look like you are.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code. And now is deleting one of the emails, but on the second iteration I got 'Cannot access a disposed OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.
Object name: 'OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client'.' error.

Comment: Don't call `Dispose()` just `Disconnect()` is enough

Comment: Once an object is disposed, it cannot be reused.  You can read up more on the using command and the dispose command.  For the code you have, it will probably work OK if you just move the disconnect and dispose commands out of the for loop

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code and now I got this error: 'You cannot delete any messages without authenticating yourself towards the server first'

Comment: Take the `Disconnect()` out of the loop, Obviously you can't delete  if you're not connected.

Comment: According to openpop documentation you need to disconnect to actually delete the email

Comment: Why don't you just try moving it out the loop then see if the exception persist